# How do I delete unique rows from a table with duplicate keys?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, duplication

I have the following data:

```
      road        |  ID  | other column  | other column | 
------------------+------+---------------+--------------+          
MAIN ST           |  1   |     ...       |     ...      |
MAIN ST           |  2   |     ...       |     ...      |        
MAIN ST           |  3   |     ...       |     ...      |
BERRY LN          |  4   |     ...       |     ...      |
BERRY LN          |  5   |     ...       |     ...      |
BERRY LN          |  6   |     ...       |     ...      |
JOHN RD           |  7   |     ...       |     ...      |
JOHN RD           |  8   |     ...       |     ...      |
```

I want all rows with duplicates in the road column removed. It does not matter to me which duplicates are removed. The end result can look something like this:

```
      road        |  ID  | other column  | other column | 
------------------+------+---------------+--------------+          
MAIN ST           |  3   |     ...       |     ...      |
BERRY LN          |  4   |     ...       |     ...      |
JOHN RD           |  8   |     ...       |     ...      |
```

where the id's are any value, as long as the road column is unique.

Is there a simple way to do this in SQL or T/SQL? I followed the guide [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444), but it only applies to duplicate keys with non-unique rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function, you could achieve that.  Here's an example below.  The top two queries are just for data verification.  I'm a firm believer that you should *see* what you will be deleting (and what will remain) before actually deleting data.

#### (Verification) Rows that *will* be deleted

```
;with cte as
(
    select
        *,
        row_num = 
            row_number() over (partition by road order by ID)
    from dbo.YourTable
)
select *
from cte
where row_num > 1;
```

#### (Verification) Rows that will *not* be deleted

```
;with cte as
(
    select
        *,
        row_num = 
            row_number() over (partition by road order by ID)
    from dbo.YourTable
)
select *
from cte
where row_num = 1;
```

#### Data Delete

*Note: the below query, when modified to fit your environment **will actually delete data**.  Therefore, you should ensure that you **really** want to delete the data, and also have a backup of the data/database prior to performing any data modification.*

```
;with cte as
(
    select
        *,
        row_num = 
            row_number() over (partition by road order by ID)
    from dbo.YourTable
)
delete from cte
where row_num > 1;
```

Comment: I have a question, doesn't this technique delete non-unique rows with the same key? In other words completely identical rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use this T/SQL :

```
DELETE 
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE 
    ( ID NOT IN
         (
             SELECT 
                MAX(ID)
             FROM dbo.YourTable
             GROUP BY road -- <List of columns that define 
                           --  duplicate's condition 
                           --  for exemple road>
         )
    )
```